# How to remove or make an Office applicaion reliquish having keyboard focus

Tags: winapi, vsto, office-interop

I have VSTO addins for Office (Excel / Word / Outlook) 2007 / 2010. Through the use of the NativeWindow the office programs listen for Hotkeys.  Upon hotkey recognition a message (WinApi SendMessage) is sent to my own application which then uses the [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd)` function to bring Internet Explorer to the front.  This works fairly well on most occasions but sometimes it does not. When it does not work the office application is left in front and the Internet Explorer icon is flashing in the task bar.

I am aware that this is by design from Microsoft for the SetForegroundWindow function to stop malicious code.

I do not know exactly why it works sometimes and not others but think it is because the user is using the keyboard to enter the hotkeys and thus the Office application does not want to give up this focus.

My first thought was to simply minimize the Office program but I do not want to do this as some people have multiple screens with Internet Explorer on one and the office application on the other.

When my VSTO addin receives the hotkey signal I would like the office application to relinquish being the foreground or active window, but I do not want it to be minimized.

I know the last paragraph might not be a correct question so maybe more generally as the VSTO addin is working with the Office application process what can I do here so that a call to SetForegroundWindow will work.

Edit: To be clear the only code I am using so far is `SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd)` where the Hwnd is that of Internet Explorer. As the conditions are now posted I am interested in creating the condition "There is no foreground process"

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The process is being debugged.
> - The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are active.
>
> **An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user.** [Emphasis Mine]

How do you know if you successfully set the foreground window?

> If the window was brought to the foreground, the return value is nonzero. 
> If the window was not brought to the foreground, the return value is zero.

Without any code to go on, there's no way to know which is causing the problem.

Comment: The only code used so far is the winapi function SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd). I am aware of the above as I linked to it. But thanks. Sometimes my App is the process that started IE but not always. The reason for my question is in your cut and copy "There is no foreground process."